# Can someone please explain this method in Java:

Tags: java

This is in a class called a resource. I'm not sure what it does and need help understanding it. trainingDTO has a UUID and an Item.

```
if (this.toDoList.addItem(trainingDto.getItem())) {
          return Response.status(200).build();
          TrainingDTO returnDTO = new TrainingDTO();
          returnDTO.setItem(trainingDto.getItem());
          UUID uuid = toDoList.findUUIDByValue(trainingDto.getItem());
          returnDTO.setUUID(uuid.toString());
          return Response.ok(returnDTO).build();
        }
```

Comment: That is not valid Java code.  You have unreachable statements following a return.

Comment: Terrible title. Edit to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining this block is a little difficult for two reasons. 1.) you didn't give us much context: i.e. we don't have the method containing the block, or any other surrounding code. 2.) this method has some odd code. That being said, let's go through line by line:

```
if (this.toDoList.addItem(trainingDto.getItem())) {
```

This `if` condition is a little complicated because `addItem()` obviously does more than just return a boolean. Generally, this is considered bad form (methods should do just one thing, and adding to a list **and** returning a boolean are two things). But that's what it does: it adds (or tries to add) to `toDoList`, and returns a boolean.

```
    return Response.status(200).build();
```

As written, this will always be the last line executed. This return statement will **always** cause the function to return, and it means the lines below will not be executed. But if it didn't, then the lines below would...

```
    TrainingDTO returnDTO = new TrainingDTO();
```

Create a new object of type `TrainingDTO`

```
    returnDTO.setItem(trainingDto.getItem());
```

Set a field of that object based on a field of an existing object (the same one referenced in the `if` condition)

```
    UUID uuid = toDoList.findUUIDByValue(trainingDto.getItem());
```

Find the value of something called a UUID for the object from the `if` condition

```
    returnDTO.setUUID(uuid.toString());
```

Use the UUID value above to set the UUID value for our new object

```
    return Response.ok(returnDTO).build();
```

Make a `Response` using the new object, and call its `build()` method, then return that result

```
}
```